# How can I filter an async list in C# UWP using MVVM?

Tags: c#, api, asynchronous, mvvm, uwp

I'm developing an UWP application following the MVVM pattern.

I want to filter a list that fills asynchronously from an API in the MainPageViewModel constructor, and at the same time I want to show a ProgressRing in the UI. For that, I'm using [Stephen Cleary's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary) [NotifyTaskCompletion class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx) to bind Task.Result to the ListView in XAML and the visibility of the ProgressRing to the NotifyTaskCompletion.IsNotComplete property.

It all works properly until here:
We want to filter that list using a textbox where the user can write, but I can't change the Task.Result to show the filtered list because it's readonly.

```
public MainPageViewModel()
{
    _listToShow = new NotifyTaskCompletion<List<Person>>(MyLists.getAsyncList());

}
```

What doesn't work:

```
private void filter()
{
    _listToShow.Result = _completeList.Where(x => x.name.Contains(_textToFilter)).ToList();
}
```

Any idea on how to change the list after being filtered without using async void methods?

Answer (score 0):

Simply change your getAsyncList return type to `Task` make the function to `await`

```
_listToShow = await MyLists.getAsyncList();

public static async Task<List<Person>> getAsyncList()
{
// your api code to retrieve person list
}
```